# twitter api problem

Tags: php, json, api, twitter

i have search the whole net for finding af NICE and easy and simple method to get twitter status and now i found one.. but it dont work

i try this 
http://tareq.wedevs.com/2009/05/playing-with-twitter-json-using-php/

but it says

"Notice:  Use of undefined constant text - assumed 'text' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/twitterWidget/twitter.php on line 8

iPad2 simulator /w Css3, Jquery and HTML5 http://t.co/GaNMTbg via @altryne"

what do i need to do?

Comment: you should accept more answers.

Comment: We definetly need to see the part of the code failing in order to help you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/tareq_cse.json?count=10", true);
$decode = json_decode($json, true);

echo "<pre>";
$count = count($decode); //counting the number of status
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
echo $decode[$i]['text']."<br>"; // in the original code there was $decode[$i][text] which is not correct
}
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

You have to put that **text** index in the 8th row into qoutes. I've posted here the corrected version.

The last code example block on that site also has the same error throughout all its lines. You must put string array indexes into quotation marks to avoid notices.

Comment: Thanks mate, do you think i can get tweets with that do :p?, it was i had hope for to get, but i cant find a good tutorial on how to make it